# Routing table optimization

Tags: algorithm, routes

The problem i am trying to solve is, I have routing table

- |src|dest|port|
- | a | b  | p1 |
- | a | b  | p2 |
- | a | b  | p3 |
- | a | c  | p1 |
- | a | d  | p2 |
- | a | e  | p3 |

This can be optimized to

- |src|dest|port|
- | a | b  |p1,p2,p3|
- | a | c  | p1 |
- | a | d  | p2 |
- | a | e  | p3 |

Which can further be optimized to

- |src|dest|port|
- | a |b,c | p1 |
- | a |b,d | p2 |
- | a |b,e | p3 |

I thought of using 3 dimensional representation to solve this problem but again the retrieval will be complicated.
I need to use the best data structure to solve this use case.

Comment: Wouldn't a further optimization be to drop the `src` column since it's redundant? At least it is in this example.

Comment: @Brent The source can be anything. This was just a use case

Comment: The first optimization allows for unique combinations of src,dest while the second one has unique ports (single-value dest or port).  Which one are you looking to use?

Comment: I need to optimize the rules i.e Rules in table 1 are further optimized to rules in table 3 as shown. I had 6 rules in table 1 which are optimized to 3 rules in table 3.

Comment: What language do you want to use with the data structure?

Answer (score 0):

The data structure is a set of sets of `dest` values, where the first set is keyed by `src` values and the second set is keyed by `port` values.  This groups `dest` values by `src` and `port`:

```
src => port => [dest]
```

In python, this can be done with dictionaries:

```
table = (
    ('a','b','p1'),
    ('a','b','p2'),
    ('a','b','p3'),
    ('a','c','p1'),
    ('a','d','p2'),
    ('a','e','p3'),
)

optimized = {}
for route in table:
    src, dest, port = route
    o = optimized.get(src, {})
    p = o.get(port, [])
    p.append(dest)
    o[port] = p
    optimized[src] = o

for src,route in optimized.iteritems():
    for port,dest in route.iteritems():
        print src, dest, port
```

The result (in unsorted order) is:

```
a ['b', 'd'] p2
a ['b', 'e'] p3
a ['b', 'c'] p1
```

The lookup can be done using:

```
dest = optimized[src][port]
```

Comment: Thank you Brent for your answer. I was able to optimize it to this level. I have added your code to https://ideone.com/PQNlwo 
Which has input table table = (
    ('a','b','p1'),
    ('a','b','p2'),
    ('a','b','p3'),
    ('a','c','p1'),
    ('a','d','p2'),
    ('a','e','p3'),
    ('b','c','p1'),
    ('b','d','p2'),
    ('b','e','p3')) 
 With Output : 
a ['b', 'd'] p2
a ['b', 'e'] p3
a ['b', 'c'] p1
b ['d'] p2
b ['e'] p3
b ['c'] p1

---- But at this level we can also derive another level of output with minimum rule set.
a, b, [p1,p2,p3]
[a,b], c, p1
[a,b], d, p2
[a,b], e, p3